# onTouchEvent in AdapterView's item

Tags: android, android-event

I have overridden the onTouchEvent method in a custom view:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull final MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("TouchEvent", String.valueOf(event.getActionMasked()));
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
       //start animation
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

That view is used in an adapter/adapterview (GridView).

However it looks like the AdapterView consumes the touch/click event and I can never see a `event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` being true. The onTouchEvent only gets notified for `ACTION_DOWN` events (the above Log.d prints only "0").

Please note that I also have an onItemClick listener attached on my AdapterView:

```
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
             //start activity
        }
});
```

I want the onTouchEvent() of my custom view to fire just before the onItemClick() of the adapter and of course being notified for any `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.